# How to run a function continuously in RN

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a sound metering app with React Native, but it seems that if I start the metering, which I have as a infinite loop until the user stops it, it hangs the app.

Basically the user taps a button, invokes startMonitor(), then the runMonitor starts and checkSound() does a check for the current decibel level.

The relevant code section here

```
startMonitor() {
    KeepAwake.activate();
    this.setState({ monitorStatus: true
    }, this.runMonitor );

  }

  runMonitor() {

    while(this.state.monitorStatus) {
      if(this.state.beginWait) {
       this.wait(5000);
     }

     if(!this.state.isTransmitting) {
        this.checkSound();
    } 
   }
  }
```

Any ideas on how to run a function continuously/infinite until the user cancels it?

Comment: do you really need the function to 'hang' ? you can when the click happens check the sound no ?

Comment: If you really need something to run continuously, write a small native module that handles this on another thread

Comment: @MaieonBrix yes, it is meant to read continuously once on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
startMonitor() {
     this.runMonitorIV = setInterval(runMonitor, 1000);
  }

  runMonitor() {

    while(this.state.monitorStatus) {
      if(this.state.beginWait) {
       this.wait(5000);
     }

     if(!this.state.isTransmitting) {
        this.checkSound();
    } 
   }
}


//called on user event
stopMonitor() {
  clearInterval(this.runMonitorIV);
}
```

(Not sure about your context or scope, but that's the basic idea)

There's also the [TimerMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers) that clears those timers triggers when a component unmounts.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: this worked for me. did not want to do setInterval but if it is the only option, then might as well. thanks for your help